# Cannot post projects in github

Tags: git, github, bitbucket

Earlier I used to use bitbucket.org. But it was not working for me as I could not push my Django projects. Whenever I gave the command:

```
git push -u origin master   

git@bitbucket.org: Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

Could not understand where I had gone wrong.
Created the repo perfectly with the command:

```
git remote add origin https://sandywandy@bitbucket.org/sandywandy/blog-app.git
```

Nothing worked. Posted queries here. None could help me. Now I have shifted to github.com. The same problem is still chasing me. And surprisingly now the error comes still with bitbucket when I am using the commands of GitHub.
If anyone has any solution please help.

Comment: What operating system are you running Git on?  Windows, Linux or Mac OS

Comment: Do you have git downloaded and installed on your machine? https://git-scm.com/downloads

Comment: Yes everything done. Its  showing git version 2.17.1

Comment: I am using Ubuntu Linux

Comment: The error message indicates that the remove server rejected your ssh key. Do whatever needs to be done on bitbucket to correctly set up your current ssh key.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cannot upload project to bitbucket.org](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52523263/cannot-upload-project-to-bitbucket-org)

Answer (score 1):

Since you are pushing with HTTPS, check if you have a [git credential helper](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Credential-Storage) which could have cached the wrong password for your private repo:

```
git config credential.helper
```

You might have to delete your cached credentials (as shown [here on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39608906/6309), or [here for MacOS](https://help.github.com/articles/updating-credentials-from-the-osx-keychain/))

Note: git remote add simply declare the repo URL in your local repo.
It does not "create" the remote repo.

Check the output of git remote -v: if it is an ssh URL (like `git@bitbucket.org:...`), change it to an https one:

```
git remote set-url origin https://sandywandy@bitbucket.org/sandywandy/blog-app.git
```

In your case:

```
git remote set-url origin https://sandywandy@bitbucket.org/sandywandy/blog-app.git
git push -u origin master
```

Comment: @SandipNath Can you try in your Git repo folder: `git remote set-url origin https://sandywandy@bitbucket.org/sandywandy/blog-app.git`, then `git push -u origin master`

Comment: Oh wonderful!!! Many many thanks VonC. It now works as it should. You are really a master VonC.